# Are problems in achieving find the separator location in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a question.

I was wondering how I can find the separator location.

Or have the date in the format **DD / MM / YYYY** without having to force the slash.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) or [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf) to find your seperator locations. If it's just a matter of formatting the date then take a look at some of the date libraries available out there.

Here are just a few:

[moments.js](http://momentjs.com/) 
[dates.js](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/) 
[xdate.js](http://arshaw.com/xdate/)

there are many more, just G* search "javascript date library"

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering if there is any function or method that I return the system date in the format:

**10/12/2012** or **12/10/2012** or last **10:12:2012**

but not manually enter the slash, colon or dash.